# nsight - OpenGL 4.2 debugging incompatibility

Tags: sdl, nvidia, glew, opengl-4

Whenever I attempt to debug a shader in nvidia nsight I get the following incompatibility in my  `nvcompatlog`.

```
glDisable (cap = 0x00008620)
        glMatrixMode
        glPushMatrix
        glLoadIdentity
        glOrtho
        glBegin
        glColor4f
        glVertex2f
        glEnd
        glPopMatrix
```

This is confusing since I am using a 4.2 core profile and not using any deprecated or fixed function calls. At this stage I am just drawing a simple 2D square to the screen and can assure none of the functions listed above are being used.

My real concern is being new to SDL & GLEW I am not sure what functions they are using behind the scene. I have been searching around the web and have found others who are using SDL, GLEW, & Nvidia nsight. This leads me to believe I am overlooking something. Below is a shortened verison of how I am initialing SDL & GLW.

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1);

SDL_Window *_window;
_window = SDL_CreateWindow("Red Square", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED  , 200, 200, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(_window);
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
GLenum status = glewInit();
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
```

In the implementation I have error checking pretty much after every call. I excluded it from the example to reduce the amount of clutter. All the above produce no errors and return valid objects.

After the initialization `glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION)` returns **4.2.0 NVIDIA 344.75**, `glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION)` returns **1.11.0**, and `GLEW_VERSION_4_2` returns **true**.

Any idea on how I can used SDL & GLEW and not have either of these frameworks call deprecated functions?

** Edit **
I have been experiementing with the Dependency Walker [here](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Looking at the calls through Opengl32.dll none of what is listed is shown as a called module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, Nsight captures all commands issued to the OpenGL server. Not just those issued through your application. If you have any FPS or recording software enabled, these tend to use deprecated methods drawing to the framebuffer. In my case it was **Riva Tuner** which displays the FPS on screen for any running games. Disabling it resolved my issue.